# Use variable value to check if particular instance exists, if not - create it

Tags: c#, class, instance

I have a list of images like this:

```
public List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
```

I also have a picture class in order to collect and manipulate data about the images in the list:

```
public Class Pic {
    // properties and stuff
}
```

And then I have a function that takes an integer as an argument. That integer corresponds to an image in the image list. What I want to do in the function is to check if an instance of the Pic class has been created for that particular image. If not, I want to create it, using the value of the variable passed into the function. The following code obviously doesn't work, but it shows what I want:

```
public void doStuffWithImage(int picNumber) {
    // Check if instance called pic + picNumber exists
    if(pic + picNumber.toString() == null) {
        // Create an instance
        Pic pic + picNumber.toString() = new Pic();
    }
}
```

Suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Try a ConcurrentDictionary and use the GetOrAdd method to retrieve an item (and create if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to create individual variables `pic1`, `pic2`, etc.  you'd be better off using a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, Pic> pics = new Dictionary<int, Pic>();

public void doStuffWithImage(int picNumber) {
    // Check if instance called pic + picNumber exists
    if(!pics.ContainsKey(picNumber)) {
        // Create an instance
        pics[picNumber] = new Pic();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "registry" of known `Pic`s. `DIctionary<int,Pic>` would be good collection to hold this registry. You need to store the registry itself somewhere - perhaps in the "factory" object that registers your pictures.

```
class PicFactory {
    private readonly IDictionary<int,Pic> knownPics = new Dictionary<int,Pic>();
    public Pic GetOrCreate(int id) {
        Pic res;
        if (knownPics.TryGetValue(id, out res)) {
            return res;
        }
        res = new Pic(id.ToString()); // This assumes that Pic(string) exists
        knownPics.Add(id, res);
        return res;
    }
}
```

This way of implementing a registry may be too primitive for your purposes - for example, if you need your registry to be concurrent, you would need to set up some sort if a locking scheme to protect the `knownPics` dictionary. The class that accesses pictures would need to create an instance of `PicFactory`, so that it could access pictures through the `GetOrCreate(id)` call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.net 4.0` or more you can use [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) type which:

> Provides support for lazy initialization.

Which means that the object will be constructed not in the moment of declaration, but when first accessed.

So you can basically declare them like

```
List<Lazy<Pic>> ....
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the Lazy Loading Pattern in general - this is actually a common optimization technique as it defers what can add up to a lot at startup to microdelays during runtime.

Be wary about making sure the microdelays are worth it, and I advise leaving methods about which can force loading.

If you're grabbing from a *list*, preface with a [`.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) check, and since you're looking up by name like that, consider using a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead